# Vb.net Missing InjectionLibrary

Tags: vb.net

In this new project i've opened up , it say that InjectionLibrary is missing :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc5gc.png
[image: InjectionLibrary]

Could anyone help me to get this to work please?
InjectionLibrary is stored into my pc or i need to download it ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a "built in" library in Visual Studio, you will have to download it, and then add the reference (usually a dll file).

Here is the process - Project >> Add Reference >> Browse >> Locate DLL in your computer >> Use the "Imports" keyword to use the library.

For further reading, take a look [here](http://www.mpgh.net/forum/292-combat-arms-spammers-injectors-multi-tools/531732-open-source-injection-library-c-printview.html).

Comment: Yeah that was i meaning , but on that forum it don't have the download of the .dll

Comment: Another user gived me the download of the .ddl now it work :D